# Inplace upgrade from sharepoint 2007 to sharepoint 2010 fails 

Tags: upgrade

I have tried without success to do an inplace upgarde of a moss 2007 installation that I would consider very basic. The upgrade process itself seems fine but after you finish the configuration wizard and it attempts to go to the upgrade status page you get

The provider 'CurrentNavigation' specified for the defaultProvider does not exist in the providers collection. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\39291\web.config line 385)

When i check the upgrade errors logs im getting the following

[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver/mysite
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: Feature upgrade failed for Feature 'PremiumSite' (Id: '8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2') in Site 'http://ehbmossserver/mysite'.
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver/mysite
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: Exception: Dependency feature with id 4c42ab64-55af-4c7c-986a-ac216a6e0c0e for feature 'PremiumSite' (id: 8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2) is not installed.
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver/mysite
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.HandleUpgradeException(Exception e, Boolean continueUpgrade, Boolean markAsUpgraded, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.Upgrade(SPFeature feature, SPWebService webService, SPWebApplication webApp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Upgrade(SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSiteWssSequence2.DoUpgrade()
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver/mysite
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [WARNING] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: Feature could not be upgraded. Exception: Feature definition id 'bcd78f28-39ed-4a12-8f19-cbe734fecc46' could not be found.
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver/mysite
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [WARNING] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: Feature could not be upgraded. Exception: Feature definition id 'f0b7efd1-95d8-422b-bce7-cefca3b7e344' could not be found.
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: Feature upgrade failed for Feature 'PremiumSite' (Id: '8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2') in Site 'http://ehbmossserver'.
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: Exception: Dependency feature with id 4c42ab64-55af-4c7c-986a-ac216a6e0c0e for feature 'PremiumSite' (id: 8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2) is not installed.
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.HandleUpgradeException(Exception e, Boolean continueUpgrade, Boolean markAsUpgraded, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.Upgrade(SPFeature feature, SPWebService webService, SPWebApplication webApp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Upgrade(SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSiteWssSequence2.DoUpgrade()
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [WARNING] [8/9/2010 2:18:36 PM]: Feature could not be upgraded. Exception: Feature definition id '00057002-c978-11da-ba52-00042350e42e' could not be found.
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:40 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver:22945/ssp/admin
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:40 PM]: Feature upgrade failed for Feature 'PremiumSite' (Id: '8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2') in Site 'http://ehbmossserver:22945/ssp/admin'.
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:40 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver:22945/ssp/admin
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:40 PM]: Exception: Dependency feature with id 4c42ab64-55af-4c7c-986a-ac216a6e0c0e for feature 'PremiumSite' (id: 8581a8a7-cf16-4770-ac54-260265ddb0b2) is not installed.
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:40 PM]: SPSite Url=http://ehbmossserver:22945/ssp/admin
[OWSTIMER] [SPSiteWssSequence2] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:40 PM]:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.HandleUpgradeException(Exception e, Boolean continueUpgrade, Boolean markAsUpgraded, Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.Upgrade(SPFeature feature, SPWebService webService, SPWebApplication webApp, SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Upgrade(SPSite site, SPWeb web, Boolean fForce)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPSiteWssSequence2.DoUpgrade()
[OWSTIMER] [SPUpgradeSession] [INFO] [8/9/2010 2:18:52 PM]: No context object
[OWSTIMER] [SPUpgradeSession] [ERROR] [8/9/2010 2:18:52 PM]: Upgrade Timer job is exiting due to exception: Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Upgrade completed with errors.  Review the upgrade log file located in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS\Upgrade-20100809-141724-147.log.  The number of errors and warnings is listed at the end of the upgrade log file.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.CheckPoint()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.LogEnd()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeJobDefinition.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)

Ive found very little info on the net about falied inplace upgrades but i would have thought this site would go through without issue. There were a couple of custom webparts which i retracted and removed properly but didnt resolve the issue. The dependency its talking about after a quick google search is supposed to be related to excel webparts, so can anybody give me any pointers ? Any help is greaetly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

So you are upgrading Moss 2007 to SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise or to Windows Foundation 2010?

As for the navigation provider message, check your web.config for that site and see what the default provider is.  Then check to make sure that provider is listed below it and then make sure that dll it is referencing is in the gac.

Comment: Upgrading to 2010 enterprise, will check the web.config to what the default provider is

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded all the pre-requisites before doing the upgrade? Please check: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx

More importantly, you need to make sure you have all the software requirements as per outlined on that URL.

If you are upgrading from MOSS 2007, I assume you MUST use the "similar" Enterprise version of Sharepoint 2010, i.e. Sharepoint Server 2010, not Sharepoint Foundation 2010.